# Many to many relationship insert and update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Many to many relationship.
I am using EntityFramework 6.1.2
For example relationship is between Users and Roles.

I need to support next scenario

Add new user without role, and than later add new roles for that user.
But when I add new user than some roles are new and some roles already exist in db, so I dont want to duplicate roles i db.

When I am adding new role I am not sure if this role exist (do i need update or add?).

I implemented scenario when I add users and roles all together. But I want to add role later, also add user later with existing roles.

What is good practice for scenarios like this?
Do you have any example?

Comment: "When I am adding new role I am not sure if this role exist" -- how can you not know whether the role you want to assign to a user exists in the DB or not? You must know that at some point. Maybe the method that adds the role to the `Roles` collection property of the user does not know that, but some method higher up the chain *has* to know, because it either creates a new role or loads a role from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there are already existing roles. Then just add the roles which are new.

```
//your roles which will be assigned to the user
var roles = new List<Roles>();

//get the ids of the existing roles
var existingRoleIds = context.Roles.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();

//filter the existing roles out
var rolesToAdd = (from r in roles
                where existingRoleIds.Contains(r.Id) == false
                select r).ToList();

//add the new roles
context.Roles.AddRange(rolesToAdd);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Ok this is part of answer. With this code I will add just new roles to role table. But now I have users in user table, roles in role table and there is nothing in UserRole table. UserRole table keeps relations between Users and Roles. Because in many to many, ther is table between users and roles.

Comment: Ok it is working now. steps are : 1- Add user, 2- Add new roles like in your example 3-Update user with new role.

Comment: Exactly, i just showed the step which adds or updates the roles :)